# Shopify false redirect of root

Tags: redirect, shopify, http-status-code-301

since yesterday shopify had problems, something strange occured at our shop: Our shop works fine, but if you go to the index/root of the shop, the starting point of the shop, it goes to https://apps.shopify.com/. That makes no sense. I didn't change anything in 3 days, everything worked fine. 
Does anyone know how I can fix this issue or what's the cause of that?

Thanks in advance

pls have a look at the GET Request: https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6Wrz.jpg

Comment: Can you share more details? It is very difficult to understand what you have asked with just an image. If possible you can share where the issue is so that the problem can be fixed.

Comment: If you go to the root of the page (/), it redirect to apps.shopify, if you got to the /index, it works, but / doesn't work

Comment: Can you share the page url?